# Slow running query comparing dates

Tags: t-sql

Could someone please offer some advice.  I have the following query that is using roughly 200,000 records.  I need to evaluate a 'DateTime' field to evaluate if the revenue occurs during the correct time slot.  I am currently using CASE statements to evaluate the DateTime field and it is an absolute pig, it runs over 5 minutes.  Is there a faster more efficient way to do this?  Note the variables @cur_date, @end_date, @prev_yr_qtr_start, @cur_date_yr_prev etc are all strings and r.pw_ship_date is of type DATETIME.  So in essence I'm comparing r.pw_ship_date to strings ie:'2017-01-01 00:00'

Note: it took 4:00 minutes to run this query when I added 'SELECT TOP(500)' for 200,000 records it would take forever.

Thanks in advance

```
DECLARE @total TABLE
(
    acct_number VARCHAR(50),
    pro_nbr VARCHAR(50),
    sales_rep VARCHAR(50),
    bill_to_name VARCHAR(50),
    billing_addr1 VARCHAR(50),
    billing_addr2 VARCHAR(50),
    billing_city CHAR(50),
    billing_state CHAR(2),
    billing_zip CHAR(10),
    cur_month_bills INT,
    cur_month_rev DECIMAL(30, 6),
    cur_qtr_bills INT,
    cur_qtr_rev DECIMAL(30, 6),
    prev_yr_qtr_bills INT,
    prev_yr_qtr_rev DECIMAL(30, 6),
    cur_ytd_bills INT,
    cur_ytd_rev DECIMAL(30, 6),
    prev_ytd_bills INT
)


INSERT  INTO @total
SELECT  TOP(50000) f.acct_number ,
        r.pro_nbr ,
        r.sales_rep ,
        r.bill_to_name ,
        r.billing_addr1 ,
        r.billing_addr2 ,
        r.billing_city ,
        r.billing_state ,
        r.billing_zip ,
        'cur_month_bills' = MAX(( CASE WHEN r.pw_ship_date BETWEEN @cur_date AND @end_date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )) ,
        'cur_month_rev' = MAX(ROUND(( CASE WHEN r.pw_ship_date BETWEEN @cur_date AND @end_date THEN f.tot_revenue ELSE 0 END ), 2)) ,
        'cur_qtr_bills' = MAX((CASE WHEN r.pw_ship_date BETWEEN @cur_date AND @end_date  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )) ,
        'cur_qtr_rev' = MAX(ROUND(CASE WHEN r.pw_ship_date BETWEEN @cur_date AND @end_date THEN f.tot_revenue ELSE 0 END, 2)) ,
        'prev_yr_qtr_bills' = MAX(CASE WHEN r.pw_ship_date BETWEEN @prev_yr_qtr_start AND @cur_date_yr_prev THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) ,
        'prev_yr_qtr_rev' = MAX(ROUND(CASE WHEN r.pw_ship_date BETWEEN @prev_yr_qtr_start AND @cur_date_yr_prev THEN f.tot_revenue ELSE 0 END , 2)) ,
        'cur_ytd_bills' = MAX(CASE WHEN r.pw_ship_date BETWEEN @first_day_cur_yr AND @end_date  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ),
        'cur_ytd_rev' = MAX(ROUND(CASE WHEN r.pw_ship_date BETWEEN @first_day_cur_yr AND @end_date THEN f.tot_revenue ELSE 0 END , 2)) ,
        'prev_ytd_bills' = MAX(CASE WHEN r.pw_ship_date BETWEEN @first_day_prev_yr AND @end_date THEN 1    ELSE 0 END )
FROM    @summed f
INNER JOIN @raw r ON f.acct_number = r.acct_number AND f.pro_nbr = r.pro_nbr
GROUP BY f.acct_number ,
        r.pro_nbr ,
        r.sales_rep ,
        r.bill_to_name ,
        r.billing_addr1 ,
        r.billing_addr2 ,
        r.billing_city ,
        r.billing_state ,
        r.billing_zip;
```

Comment: You should change all of the variables to `DateTime`. (See [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) for details.) You could also add a `where` clause to limit the range of rows processed to the earliest and latest dates you need, i.e. `@first_day_prev_yr` is likely the minimum and `@end_date` the maximum. (I'm assuming that there is data outside that range in the tables.) Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`.

Comment: Please show how you're creating your table variables `@raw` and `@summed`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your table variables `@raw` and `@summed` to temporary tables. Table variables have no statistics and are *extremely* limited with regard to indexing (you can only have one). Because of this, SQL Server assumes that your table variables have only one row (2012 and older) or 100 rows (2014+). This means that you almost certainly are getting a bad execution plan for your query, and that's going to ruin you.

Once you've changed `@raw` and `@summed` into `#raw` and `#summed`, put an index on  them - at a minimum, index your foreign keys (the fields you're joining on), `acct_number` and `pro-nbr`. It *may* be worth creating a clustered index and/or a primary key as well, but that's something you'll need to experiment with to find the performance you require.

The other thing that is killing your performance is comparing `datetime`s to strings. This is causing a type conversion and that can drag you down significantly. If you're working with a date/time, **use the appropriate data type** - not a string that *looks like* a date.

If this is still not running quickly enough, move your `CASE` statements out of your aggregate functions.

`MAX(( CASE WHEN r.pw_ship_date BETWEEN @cur_date AND @end_date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ))`

Move the `CASE` statement into the query that populates `#raw.pw_ship_date` so that when you're performing the aggregate, you're just looking at integers all the way down.